# add item containing accute accent to TComboBox (FMX)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I am running a query that populates a TComboBox to let users filter results displayed in a ListView.  One of the query results has an [E with an accute accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89) character.  The word is `CIGRÉ`.  It shows up in my ComboBox as `CIGR...`, as shown below.

[image]

I have been scrubbing the data to replace the `É` with an `E`.  Is there a way to modify the query so it retains the original `É`?

Below is my query code, it returns unique committee names from a big list of meetings (mtgs).

```
Form1->FDConnection1->Params->Values["ColumnMetadataSupported"] = "False";
Form1->FDConnection1->Params->Values["Database"] = System::Ioutils::TPath::Combine(System::Ioutils::TPath::GetDocumentsPath(), "local.db");  // i'm using ifdefs to set this properly for platform (not shown)

query->SQL->Text = "SELECT DISTINCT committee FROM mtgs ORDER BY committee";
query->Open();
while (!query->Eof) {
  Form1->cmbBoxFilters->Items->Add("Show " + query->FieldByName("committee")->AsString);
  query->Next();
}
```

p.s.  I'm building in C++Builder 10.2 Version 25.0.29899.2631 and the app is for Win32, iOS, and Android. I'm using FireDAC to access the db.  The `committee` field is type TEXT. The TFDConnection setting for Driver is SQLite.  The db file is SQLite version 3 (SQLite3).

UPDATE 1:  I have been using [SQLiteManager](https://www.sqlabs.com/) to import CSV data into my db.  I've set it to UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32 and all give the same result.  The `CIGRÉ` gets converted to `CIGR...` by SQLiteManager.  This is clearly not a problem with my code.  I apologize for wasting folks time.

[image: screen snag of SQLiteManager import window]

Comment: What database are you using? What framework are you using to access it? What encoding does the database use for the `committee` field?

Comment: I added 2 lines to top of code and some verbiage below the code to answer Remy's questions above (hopefully).

Comment: Did you verify that `query->FieldByName("committee")->AsString` is actually returning the correct string value?  Is the string data being altered by FireDAC itself, or by the ComboBox? By default, the SQLite driver for FireDAC treats `TEXT` fields as Unicode (double-check the `StringFormat` attribute on the connection settings), so I would expect `AsString` to be able to return `'CIGRÈ'` as expected. Does the problem occur on all platforms, or just some of them?

Comment: I'm headed home to check.  I upgraded my office machine to Rio 10.3 and and getting tons of [errors about overloading](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T698302/the-functions-that-differ-only-in-their-return-type-cannot-be-overloaded-error-occurs-on).  My home machine is still on Tokyo 10.2.3.

Comment: I erred, it is actually an [E with the accute accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89), not the grave accent.  So, 'CIGRÉ', not 'CIGRÈ'. I've edited my question to correct though not sure it alters anything.

Comment: I added a `ShowMessage(query->FieldByName("committee")->AsString)` inside the While loop and when it gets to the `CIGRÉ` it shows `CIGR...`.  This on iOS, Win32, and Android.

Comment: `StringFormat` in the FDConnection1 attributes was set to "Choose".  I changed it to both of the other options (Unicode or ANSI) and same result of `CIGR...`.

Comment: Stop the presses!  This may be a bug in [SQLiteManager's](https://www.sqlabs.com/) import routine.  I've described at bottom of my question as UPDATE 1.